# WooCommerce Select2 match US/ Canada, etc states by beginning of string not just any match

Tags: woocommerce, jquery-select2, dropdown, matcher

WooCommerce uses select2 in the shipping and billing address field for state and country. I want to make it so that when you search for `ka` the top result is `Kansas` not `Alaska`.

I checked the documentation for select2 and found this:

https://select2.org/searching#customizing-how-results-are-matched

But that solution is for when there are children. I don't know how to edit the documented example to make it work with WooCommerce. Another SO article suggests this:

```
function matchCustom(term, text) {
  console.log('matcher is running');
  if (text.toUpperCase().indexOf(term.toUpperCase()) == 0) {
    return true;
  }
}
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {

  $(".state_select").select2({
    matcher: matchCustom
  });
});
```

With the above code, when I search for `ka` the top result is `Alaska` not `Kansas`.

I looked at the following SO questions:

[jquery select2 plugin how to match only beginning of word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31461303/jquery-select2-plugin-how-to-match-only-beginning-of-word)

[jquery select2 plugin how to get only the result 'myString%'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15809594/jquery-select2-plugin-how-to-get-only-the-result-mystring?rq=1)

[select2 search - match only words that start with search term](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31571864/select2-search-match-only-words-that-start-with-search-term)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like so:

1. The script file (I named it `my-wc-country-select.js`):

   ```
   jQuery( function( $ ){
       if ( ! $().selectWoo ) {
           return;
       }

       // Based on <https://select2.org/searching#customizing-how-results-are-matched>
       function matchCustom(params, data) {
           // If there are no search terms, return all of the data
           if ($.trim(params.term) === '') {
               return data;
           }

           // Do not display the item if there is no 'text' property
           if (typeof data.text === 'undefined') {
               return null;
           }

           // `params.term` should be the term that is used for searching
           // `data.text` is the text that is displayed for the data object
           var s = $.trim( params.term ).toLowerCase();
           var s2 = $.trim( data.text ).toLowerCase();
           if ( s === s2.substr( 0, s.length ) ) {
               return data;
           }

           // Return `null` if the term should not be displayed
           return null;
       }

       function country_select_select2() {
           // Apply the custom "matcher" to the country and state drop-downs.
           $( 'select.country_select:visible, select.state_select:visible' ).selectWoo( {
               // We're just changing this option.
               matcher: matchCustom
           } );
       }

       country_select_select2();

       $( document.body ).bind( 'country_to_state_changed', function() {
           country_select_select2();
       });
   } );
   ```

   [Reference](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/woocommerce/tags/3.7.0/assets/js/frontend/country-select.js)
2. Load the file on the front-end: (this code would go in the theme functions file)

   ```php
   wp_enqueue_script( 'my-wc-country-select', 'path/to/my-wc-country-select.js', [ 'wc-country-select' ] );
   ```

   *Make sure `wc-country-select` is added as a dependency.*

Comment: It works, thank you and sorry for the delay in responding. This was a backlog item for me.